# Memory Leak handling while terminating thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, pthreads

I am writing here a C pgm, which creates a thread and process it. To avoid the memory leak by the thread I am using the pthread_cleanup_push and pthread_cleanup_pop function, and calling pthread_exit at last on the thread function.   While running the program I get following error.

I believe some memory allocation/ free issue is there. Please help me out, how can I safely terminate the thread with no memory leak. Below is my program :-

```
struct str_thrd_data
{
        SQLHANDLE hstmt;
        int rc;
        bool thrd_completed_flag;
};

void * str_in_thread_call(void *in_str_arg)
{
        int thrd_rc;
        struct str_thrd_data *str_arg;
        str_arg = in_str_arg;

        pthread_cleanup_push(free, str_arg);
        thrd_rc = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);
        if (thrd_rc != 0)
               handle_error_en(thrd_rc, "pthread_setcancelstate");

        thrd_rc = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
        if (thrd_rc != 0)
               handle_error_en(thrd_rc, "pthread_setcancelstate");

        printf("\n*********************Normal Thread termination withing timelimit %d\n",str_arg->rc);
        str_arg->thrd_completed_flag = true;
        sleep(1);
        pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
        pthread_exit(1);
}

int main()
{
        printf("\nPJH: New THread created.\n");
        pthread_attr_t tattr;
        pthread_t th;
        size_t mysize = 1;

        struct str_thrd_data atd;

        atd.hstmt = hstmt;
        atd.rc= rc;
        atd.thrd_completed_flag = false;

        thrd_rc = pthread_attr_init(&tattr);
        thrd_rc = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&tattr, mysize);
        thrd_rc = pthread_create(&th, &tattr, &str_in_thread_call, &atd);
        if (thrd_rc != 0)
               handle_error_en(thrd_rc, "pthread_create");

        while(timeout !=0)
        {
                printf("%d Value of rc=%d\n",timeout, atd.rc);
                if(atd.rc != 999) break;
                timeout--;
                usleep(10000);
        }
        rc = atd.rc;
}
```

Below is the error message I get, when running the program:-

```
*** glibc detected *** ./myprocessname: free(): invalid pointer: 0xbc8d9f34 ***  
======= Backtrace: =========  
/lib/libc.so.6[0x5e0c65]  
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x59)[0x5e4c59]  
./dcs[0x80a828a]  
/lib/libpthread.so.0[0x7c4912]  
/lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0x64c60e]  
======= Memory map: ========  
00558000-00573000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 393227                             /lib/ld-2.5.so  
00573000-00574000 r--p 0001a000 fd:00 393227                             /lib/ld-2.5.so  
00574000-00575000 rw-p 0001b000 fd:00 393227                             /lib/ld-2.5.so  
00577000-006ce000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 393228                             /lib/libc-2.5.so  
006ce000-006d0000 r--p 00156000 fd:00 393228                             /lib/libc-2.5.so  
006d0000-006d1000 rw-p 00158000 fd:00 393228                             /lib/libc-2.5.so  
006d1000-006d4000 rw-p 006d1000 00:00 0  
006d6000-006fd000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 393234                             /lib/libm-2.5.so  
006fd000-006fe000 r--p 00026000 fd:00 393234                             /lib/libm-2.5.so  
006fe000-006ff000 rw-p 00027000 fd:00 393234                             /lib/libm-2.5.so  
007a1000-007a8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 393417                             /lib/librt-2.5.so  
007a8000-007a9000 r--p 00007000 fd:00 393417                             /lib/librt-2.5.so  
007a9000-007aa000 rw-p 00008000 fd:00 393417                             /lib/librt-2.5.so  
007bf000-007d5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 393230                             /lib/libpthread-2.5.so  
007d5000-007d6000 r--p 00015000 fd:00 393230                             /lib/libpthread-2.5.so  
007d6000-007d7000 rw-p 00016000 fd:00 393230                             /lib/libpthread-2.5.so  
007d7000-007d9000 rw-p 007d7000 00:00 0  
007db000-007e6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 393252                             /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.20080825.so.1  
007e6000-007e7000 rw-p 0000a000 fd:00 393252                             /lib/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1  
007e9000-007ec000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 393237                             /lib/libdl-2.5.so  
007ec000-007ed000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 393237                             /lib/libdl-2.5.so    
007ed000-007ee000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 393237                             /lib/libdl-2.5.so  
00acd000-00adf000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 393296                             /lib/libz.so.1.2.3  
00adf000-00ae0000 rw-p 00011000 fd:00 393296                             /lib/libz.so.1.2.3  
08048000-0810c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1517776                            /home/myprocessname  
0810c000-08185000 rw-p 000c3000 fd:01 1517776                            /home/myprocessname  
08185000-08215000 rw-p 08185000 00:00 0  
0857b000-08aee000 rw-p 0857b000 00:00 0                                  [heap]  
1ffea000-1ffeb000 ---p 1ffea000 00:00 0  
1ffeb000-3f3eb000 rwxp 1ffeb000 00:00 0  
3f3eb000-3f42c000 rw-p 3f3eb000 00:00 0  
3f42c000-3f44c000 rw-s 00000000 00:09 1570996267                         /SYSV00000000 (deleted)  
3f44c000-3f48c000 rw-p 3f44c000 00:00 0  
3f48c000-3f4ac000 rw-s 00000000 00:09 1570963498                         /SYSV00000000 (deleted)  
3f4ac000-3f4cc000 rw-s 00000000 00:09 1570930729                         /SYSV00000000 (deleted)  
3f4cc000-3f58c000 rw-p 3f4cc000 00:00 0  
3f58c000-3f5ac000 rw-s 00000000 00:09 1570897960                         /SYSV00000000 (deleted)  
3f5ac000-3f62c000 rw-p 3f5ac000 00:00 0  
3f62c000-3f64c000 rw-s 00000000 00:09 1570865191                         /SYSV00000000 (deleted)  
3f64c000-3f6cc000 rw-p 3f64c000 00:00 0  
3f6cc000-3f6ec000 rw-s 00000000 00:09 1570832422                         /SYSV00000000 (deleted)  
3f6ec000-3f70c000 rw-s 00000000 00:09 1570799653                         /SYSV00000000 (deleted)  
3f70c000-3f72c000 rw-s 00000000 00:09 1570766884                         /SYSV00000000 (deleted)  
3f72c000-3f8ec000 rw-p 3f72c000 00:00 0  
3f8ec000-3f8ed000 ---p 3f8ec000 00:00 0  
3f8ed000-5eced000 rwxp 3f8ed000 00:00 0  
5eced000-5ecee000 ---p 5eced000 00:00 0  
5ecee000-7e0ee000 rwxp 5ecee000 00:00 0Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Instead of busy-waiting on the thread to exit in the main thread, you should call `pthread_join`. This also frees some data used internal by the thread system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to free memory on the stack for the `main` function. That will of course not work.

In your `pthread_create` call you use `&atd`, this will return a pointer to the `atd` structure on the stack of the `main` function. This memory can not, and should not, be freed by you.

Comment: I dont want to release the structure atd. I want to release all the local memory used by the thread function str_in_thread_call, once it gets completed. Can you suggest me how can I achieve it, and the way I have used "pthread_cleanup_push(free, str_arg) and pthread_cleanup_pop(1)" Is it correct ?

Comment: @PalLoveCoding But `str_arg` is taken from the thread argument, which is `&atd`. `pthread_create` does not allocate new memory, how could it as you don't even provide a size of the data you pass? Since threads share memory space you just get the actual pointer you pass to `pthread_create`.

Comment: @PalLoveCoding It would be very easy to check in a debugger. Set a breakpoint on the `pthread_create` call, and one on the thread function. Compare the values of `&atd` and `in_str_arg`. You will see that they are indeed the same, meaning they both point to the same memory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions:- I have done gdb and found that while passing the address are same for '&atd' and 'in_str_arg'. But when I typecast it to 'str_arg' it creates a different memory address. I want to delete all the memories except '&atd'. here are the gdb o/put:- (gdb) p &atd
$1 = (struct str_thrd_data *) 0x5ec8ff34

Comment: (gdb) p &atd
$1 = (struct str_thrd_data *) 0x5ec8ff34   Breakpoint 2, str_in_thread_call (in_str_arg=0x5ec8ff34) at dcs_db2_execute.c:331
331             str_arg = in_str_arg;
(gdb) p &in_str_arg
$2 = (void **) 0x3f457230
(gdb) n
333             pthread_cleanup_push(free, &in_str_arg);
(gdb) p &str_arg
$3 = (struct str_thrd_data **) 0x3f457210
(gdb)  Breakpoint 2, str_in_thread_call (in_str_arg=0x5ec8ff34) at dcs_db2_execute.c:331
331             str_arg = in_str_arg;
(gdb) p &in_str_arg
$2 = (void **) 0x3f457230
(gdb) p &str_arg
$3 = (struct str_thrd_data **) 0x3f457210
(gdb)

Comment: @PalLoveCoding You're either missing his point, or do not understand what `pthread_create()` does. *It doesn't allocate memory from, or for, your passed-in argument*. Your debug is printing the *address* of a stack variable (which happens to be a pointer); not the actual address *in* the pointer variable. In main, try `(gdb)p &atd`, then in your thread proc, `(gdb)p in_str_arg`. you'll see, they're the *same address*. (and +1 on the answer, Joachim).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg,@WhozCraig : I understood the point that, thread function is not creating any extra memory space as per the code written. But still when I see the pmap in unix for the running process, it says that the newly created thread keeps consuming the Memory Space (as per the Default Stack Size ulimit -s). When completion of thread function, Should Not the memory get released from the pmap?Assume that My Main calls the thread function several times a day,in that case slowly -2 all the Memory space gets full, and later I get eror message "Pthread_create: Resouce Not Available." why So ?

Comment: @PalLoveCoding You need to _join_ the thread after it's done, with `pthread_join`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg The problem solved by `pthread_join`. It has to be taken in use after pthread_cancel or pthread_exit to release the used memory space by the thread. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: You can also create your thread as being detached, by calling `pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&tattr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);` before `pthread_create`. Then you do not need to join the thread, but on the other hand, can't get any return value from it either (which you'd otherwise be able to when joining).

Answer (score 1):

One more problem whith above code is `thrd_rc = pthread_attr_setstacksize(&tattr, mysize);` this `mysize` should be multiple of system page size otherwise function will fail.